# How can I configure the client timeout to yugabyte db server when running queries from psql?

Tags: psql, yugabytedb

It seems like some queries are taking too long and I want to make the client wait longer for the query results?

Answer (score 0):

By default there's no statement timeout:

```
yugabyte=# show statement_timeout;
 statement_timeout 
-------------------
 0
(1 row)

yugabyte=# select pg_sleep(2);
 pg_sleep 
----------

(1 row)

yugabyte=# set statement_timeout to 1000;
SET
yugabyte=# select pg_sleep(2);
ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
```

Can you tell me what error are you getting ?